# Practical jitter with clock_nanosleep()

Tags: c, timer, jitter

I'm trying to establish what practical jitter I can achieve by using `clock_nanosleep()` in a loop and through experimentation I'm observing something I'm not confident I understand.

I'm using code posted in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52095008/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-periodic-linux-threads-in-c) by another user to benchmark performance, targeting a 250ms interval. I've observed that on my system the sleep function returns very consistently 10us late with only about 2us jitter the vast majority of the time (fairly narrow statistical distribution).

NOTE: I haven't collected data to present a plot of statistical distribution but casual qualitative description should hopefully suffice.

I decided to subtract the 10us offset from the target wakeup time to compensate for it, and this caused the average error to be approximately zero as expected, however the jitter increased dramatically - I would estimate most wakeups are >100us early/late, and much more widely distributed.

Why is this?

My theory is that with the 10us correction the target waketimes are less nicely aligned with the underlying hardware clock, but it would be helpful to get confirmation. If this is true, is there a method to synchronize the phase of the target waketimes with the hardware clock?

Comment: If you don't use an RTOS, you cannot have near-jitter-free timings at all. Some desktop systems are known to "sleep" for seconds at times. But even if you have full control, for example when using a bare metal system, you will experience jitter in the nano- or micro-seconds range. This is just because of potentially different execution times of machine instructions, and depends on the specific target and its system clock.

Comment: Agreed regarding your points about RTOS. To be clear, I'm not looking to have jitter-free or near-jitter-free operation, I'm looking to see what is practically achievable in terms of the statistical distribution of jitter, and wondering why having a constant offset in my periodic waketime target has such a significant impact on this.

Answer (score 1):

Manpages for [clock_nanosleep(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_nanosleep.2.html) say: "Furthermore, after the
sleep completes, there may still be a delay before the CPU
becomes free to once again execute the calling thread."

I tried to comprehend your question. For this I created the source code below based on the reference at SO which you provided. I include the source code such that you or someone else can check it, test it, play with it.

The debug print refers to a sleep of exactly 1 second. The debug print is shorter than the print in the comments - and the debug print will always refer to the deviation from 1 second, no matter which wakeTime has been defined. Thus, it is possible, to try a reduced wakeTime (wakeTime.tv_nsec-= some_value;) to achieve the target of 1 second.

Conclusions:

- I would generally agree to all you (davegravy) write about it in your post, except that I am seeing much higher delays and deviations.
- There are minor changes in the delay between a non-loaded and a heavy loaded system (all CPUs 100% load). On heavy loaded system scattering of delay reduces and the average delay also reduces (on my system - but not very significant).
- As expected, the delay changes quite a bit when I try it on another machine (as expected raspberry pi is worse :o).
- For a specific machine and moment it is possible to define a correction value of nanoseconds to bring the average sleep closer to the target. Anyway, the correction value is not necessarily equal to the delay error without correction. And the correction value might be different for different machines.

**Idea:** As the provided code can measure how good it is. There might be the chance, that the code does a few loops from which it can derive an optimized delay correction value by itself. (This auto-correction might be interesting just from a theoretical point of view. Well, it is an idea.)

**Idea 2:** Or some correction values can be created just to avoid a long-term shift when considering many intervals, one after another.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CLOCK CLOCK_MONOTONIC
//#define CLOCK CLOCK_REALTIME
//#define CLOCK CLOCK_TAI
//#define CLOCK CLOCK_BOOTTIME


static long calcTimeDiff(struct timespec const* t1, struct timespec const* t2)
{
  long diff = t1->tv_nsec - t2->tv_nsec;
  diff += 1000000000 * (t1->tv_sec - t2->tv_sec);
  return diff;
}

static void* tickThread()
{
  struct timespec sleepStart;
  struct timespec currentTime;
  struct timespec wakeTime;
  long sleepTime;
  long wakeDelay;


  while(1)
  {
      clock_gettime(CLOCK, &wakeTime);
      wakeTime.tv_sec += 1;
      wakeTime.tv_nsec -= 0; //  Value to play with for delay "correction"
    
    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &sleepStart);
    clock_nanosleep(CLOCK, TIMER_ABSTIME, &wakeTime, NULL);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &currentTime);
    sleepTime = calcTimeDiff(&currentTime, &sleepStart);
    wakeDelay = calcTimeDiff(&currentTime, &wakeTime);
    {
      /*printf("sleep req=%-ld.%-ld start=%-ld.%-ld curr=%-ld.%-ld sleep=%-ld delay=%-ld\n",
          (long) wakeTime.tv_sec, (long) wakeTime.tv_nsec,
          (long) sleepStart.tv_sec, (long) sleepStart.tv_nsec,
          (long) currentTime.tv_sec, (long) currentTime.tv_nsec,
          sleepTime, wakeDelay);*/
          
        // Debug Short Print with respect to target sleep = 1 sec. = 1000000000 ns
        long debugTargetDelay=sleepTime-1000000000;
        printf("sleep=%-ld delay=%-ld targetdelay=%-ld\n",    
          sleepTime, wakeDelay, debugTargetDelay);    
    }
  }
}


int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
  tickThread();
}
```

Some output with `wakeTime.tv_nsec -= 0;`

```
sleep=1000095788 delay=96104 targetdelay=95788
sleep=1000078989 delay=79155 targetdelay=78989
sleep=1000080717 delay=81023 targetdelay=80717
sleep=1000068001 delay=68251 targetdelay=68001
sleep=1000080475 delay=80519 targetdelay=80475
sleep=1000110925 delay=110977 targetdelay=110925
sleep=1000082415 delay=82561 targetdelay=82415
sleep=1000079572 delay=79713 targetdelay=79572
sleep=1000098609 delay=98664 targetdelay=98609
```

and with `wakeTime.tv_nsec -= 65000;`

```
sleep=1000031711 delay=96987 targetdelay=31711
sleep=1000009400 delay=74611 targetdelay=9400
sleep=1000015867 delay=80912 targetdelay=15867
sleep=1000015612 delay=80708 targetdelay=15612
sleep=1000030397 delay=95592 targetdelay=30397
sleep=1000015299 delay=80475 targetdelay=15299
sleep=999993542 delay=58614 targetdelay=-6458
sleep=1000031263 delay=96310 targetdelay=31263
sleep=1000002029 delay=67169 targetdelay=2029
sleep=1000031671 delay=96821 targetdelay=31671
sleep=999998462 delay=63608 targetdelay=-1538
```

Anyway, the delays change all the time. I tried different CLOCK definitions and different compiler options, but without any special results.

**Some statistics** from further testing, sample size = 100 in both cases.
targetdelay from `wakeTime.tv_nsec -= 0;`
Mean value = 97503 Standard deviation = 27536

targetdelay from `wakeTime.tv_nsec -= 97508;`
Mean value = -1909 Standard deviation = 32682

In both cases, there were a few massive outliers, such that even this result from 100 samples might not quite be representative.